# how to get the cell value from table and assign to the variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to assign the output of split to the variable, how can do this, i tried this

```
DECLARE @StartMonth nvarchar(5) = select top 1 Value from dbo.split('jun - may', '-')
```

Step 1:

```
select top 1 Value from dbo.split('jun - may', '-')
```

Output is `jun`

Step 2:

I need to assign it to the variable `@StartMonth`

Comment: I assume you want to assign each value resulted from `split` to your variable and then perform some other operations with it. You can accomplish this with a cursor but... explain better what are you trying to do with the values resulted from split. There must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @StartMonth nvarchar(5) 
select top 1 @StartMonth = Value from dbo.split('jun - may', '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
DECLARE @StartMonth nvarchar(5)

select top 1 @StartMonth = Value from dbo.split('jun - may', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

Declare @StartMonth nvarchar(5)

select top 1 @StartMonth = Value from dbo.split('jun - may', '-')